# Java Error:cannot find or load main class java

Tags: java

I am trying to setup a simple rmi server

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class EmployeeServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Employee{

private String name,id;
private int salary;
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

public EmployeeServer(String n,String i,int s) throws RemoteException {
    super();
    name=n;
    id=i;
    salary=s;
}

public String getName() throws RemoteException {
    return name;
}


public String getID() throws RemoteException {
    return id;
}


public int getSalary() throws RemoteException {
    return salary;
}


public int augmentSalary(int howMuch) throws RemoteException {
    if(howMuch>0){
        salary+=howMuch;
    }
    return salary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, AlreadyBoundException {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    EmployeeServer server=new EmployeeServer("Red","0123",5000);
    Naming.rebind("Red", server);
    System.out.println("Server Ready!");
}
}
```

With this code alone i was getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

After A LOT of googling i finally wrote my policy file

```
grant codeBase "file:/Utenti/Super/workspacenew/PDEsercizioStubSkeleton2.0/bin/EmployeeServer.class" 
{
permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:1099", "connect, resolve";
};
```

And put it in my project folder "PDEsercizioStubSkeleton2.0".
Now i was trying to include this policy file in my jvm run configurations putting this in the VM arguments:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=server.policy
```

But then it gives me the "Error: could not find or load the main class java".
I found out it just checks the first word wrote, because i modified "java" with "jaa" and got the same error with the misspelled name. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you actually put `java -Djava.security,manager...` into a box labelled 'VM arguments', then the command line run will quite probably be `java java -Djava.security.manager...`, or perhaps `/path/to/some/java java -Djava.security.manager...`. Try removing `java` from the 'VM arguments'.

Comment: If i remove "java" then i have this error again: Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Comment: In that case either (a) the security policy file isn't being found, or (more likely) (b) the codeBase entry should be the directory containing the source code rather than a class itself.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Comment: @LukeWoodward The codebase doesn't have anything to do with the permission problem. Baffled why you would think otherwise. The policy file isn't being found, or doesn't contain the right stuff.

Comment: @EJP Can you please tell me which is the right way to write the file path? I've read it starts searching from the project folder, and i have my policy file exactly in the project folder, that's why i wrote "-Djava.security.policy=server.policy". The exact name of my policy file is "server.policy". Also, do i have to put the whole string in VM arguments in ""? Or without the ""? I'm assuming the only right thing is the policy file itself because i wrote it with the default policy tool.

Comment: @EJP: I suspect I confused 'code source location' as written in the linked article (better wording undoubtedly possible) with 'source code location'.  Sorry.

Comment: @EugenioAlbano 1. You don't need quotes. 2. It searches in the current working directory. 3. This problem had exactly nothing do with RMI.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Neither of those has anything to do with the permission problem. Still baffled.

Comment: @EJP I solved it. I re-created the policy file inside eclipse and now it sees it, even if the two policy files are in the same directory it sees just the one created inside Eclipse. Anyway, after that i was getting the error 

java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Interfaces.RemoteMethodIntf

And i solved it by adding this line in my code:
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1098);

Comment: @EJP Now i'm getting this error:
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;

I tried adding -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 into my VM arguments but still i get the same error, what to do now?

My actual VM arguments are these:
-Djava.security.policy=securit.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1

Comment: @EJP I solved everything by modifying the policy file to just include this "permission java.security.AllPermission;"      My question now is: Is there any more specific permission i can use to make it work?